# Inkscape: how to attach superscript and subscript to the same character

Tags: inkscape, subscript, superscript

I want to add both superscript and subscript to the same character in the Inkscape text object. Currently, I have this: [image]

but I want apostrophe (') and 0 to be aligned vertically so that x has (') as superscript and 0 as subscript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use negative horizontal kerning on your zero indices. Look at the red framed field in the upper right.

[image: Screenshot from Inkscape]

The SVG for the text element will look like this:

```
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.584px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.2646"
   x="29.4"
   y="29.48"
   id="text3715"><tspan
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan3713"
     x="29.4"
     y="29.48"
     style="stroke-width:0.2646"
     dx="0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 3.5">(x'<tspan
style="font-size:65%;baseline-shift:sub"
id="tspan3717"
dx="-3.5">0</tspan>,y'<tspan
style="font-size:65%;baseline-shift:sub"
id="tspan3719"
dx="-3.5">0</tspan>)</tspan></text>
```

Note the `dx="-3.5"` attributes.